Using Collect on constant terms within an equation with derivative terms
I would like to use the Collect[] function to gather terms that have the same powers for some constant parameter a.
For example:
y = a*s1 + a^2*s2 + a^3*s3
Collect[y'' + y' + y^2 + y, a]

This gives me a result where the terms without primes are collected as I would like, but the terms with primes are all gathered together:
$$a^6 \text{(s3)}^2+2 a^5 \text{(s2)} \text{(s3)}+a^4 \left(2 \text{(s1)}\text{(s3)}+\text{(s2)}^2\right)+a^3 (2 \text{(s1)} \text{(s2)}+\text{(s3)})+a^2\left(\text{(s1)}^2+\text{(s2)}\right)+\left(a^3 \text{(s3)}+a^2 \text{(s2)}+a\text{(s1)}\right)'+\left(a^3 \text{(s3)}+a^2 \text{(s2)}+a \text{(s1)}\right)''+a \text{(s1)}$$
How would I be able to move these constant a terms out of the derivative so that I can use collect on them? I have also tried to set a to a constant with: SetAttributes[a, Constant]

You might want to distinguish expressions that are formulas from expressions that are functions. Mathematica has distinct operators for each. A formula represents a quantity; a function may be applied to one or more arguments, and when applied to the correct number of arguments, it becomes a formula. Sin[x] is a formula; Sin is a function. Derivatives of formulas may be found with D[]; derivatives of single-argument functions may be found with ' (prime, the same as Derivative[1]). So D[Sin[x], x], not Sin[x]'. I guess y' might mean D[y, a], but it's not clear.

Since no arguments are given to the functions s1,s2,s3, Derivative can do nothing. One way is to add an argument variable x to them:
Clear["Global`*"];
y = a*s1[x] + a^2*s2[x] + a^3*s3[x];
Collect[D[y, {x, 2}] + D[y, x] + y^2 + y, a]


Another possible solution is to replace Derivative by total derivative Dt:
Clear["Global`*"];
y = a*s1 + a^2*s2 + a^3*s3;
Collect[Dt[Dt[y]] + Dt[y] + y^2 + y /. Dt[a] -> 0, a]



What is the difference between Derivative[] and Dt[]? I see from the Mathematica documentation there is a Constants->{} option, but that was not used in your second example here.

Derivative is a MMA implementation of partial derivatives. So you need to specify which argument you are differentiating. On the other hand, Dt is a MMA implementation of total derivative, or, differential operator (in the sense of de Rham theory). The latter is well-defined independent of choice of the coordinates (i.e. variables). In stead of using Constants option, I added a rule Dt[a] -> 0, which means $a$ does not depend on any other variables, or equivalently, $a$ is a constant.
